# How to solve the error "Unable to locate package libuhd003" for ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to install usrp200 mini in ubuntu20.04 but this error is occureing after the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install libuhd-dev libuhd003 uhd-host
```

Comment: What guide are you following ? Is it for 20.04 or for an older Ubuntu version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that installation of [*libuhd-dev*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libuhd-dev) package will be enough:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libuhd-dev
```

Other installation candidates may be [found here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&searchon=names&keywords=uhd), like

```
sudo apt-get install libuhd3.15.0 uhd-host
```

Comment: I actually received an error: `E: Unable to locate package libuhd3.15.0`. Is could be outdated?

Comment: It depends on Ubuntu version. See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=uhd for package name suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old topic, but I had that issue and here's the solution, found on [this Ettus KB](https://files.ettus.com/manual/page_install.html#install_linux_ourbins_ubuntu)

> Copy and paste these commands into your terminal. This will install
> UHD software as well as allow you to receive package updates.
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ettusresearch/uhd
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install libuhd-dev libuhd003 uhd-host