# B200 mini USRP driver installation

Tags: drivers

I am trying to install USRP B200 Mini in my laptop ubuntu 18.04, the installation process is showing completed but I can not find where the UHD driver is located. How can I make sure then the UHD driver is successfully installed in my laptop. I have used the following code for my installation:

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ettusresearch/uhd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libuhd-dev libuhd003 uhd-host
```

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/1264683/66509 .

Answer (score 0):

One way to find where the installed files are supposed to be would be to use apt-file command. It should tell you the path where files are or would be installed.
There are two ways of using it:

- apt-file show pkg - Listing the files in the package
- apt-file search pattern  - search for the file name matching pattern

For example, in my ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine the following shows the content of libuhd003.010.003 package:

```
$ apt-file show libuhd003.010.003
libuhd003.010.003: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuhd.so.003.010.003
libuhd003.010.003: /usr/share/doc/libuhd003.010.003/changelog.Debian.gz
libuhd003.010.003: /usr/share/doc/libuhd003.010.003/copyright
```

Similarly, the following command shows packages and locations for the files with names matching pattern 'libuhd.so'

```
$ apt-file search libuhd.so
libuhd-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuhd.so
libuhd003.010.003: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuhd.so.003.010.003
```

You can then check if the files are in their expected location.